# CSS list-style: none; still shows bullet

Tags: css

I am using YUI reset/base, after the reset it sets the `ul` and `li` tags to list-style: disc outside;

My markup looks like this:

```
<div id="nav">
     <ul class="links">
         <li><a href="">Testing</a></li>
     </ul>

</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
#nav {}
#nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
 }
```

Now that makes the small disc beside each li disappear.

Why doesn't this work though?

```
 #nav {}
 #nav ul.links 
 {
      list-style: none;
 }
```

It works if I remove the link to the base.css file, why?.

Updated: `sidenav` -> `nav`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that Dan was close with his answer, but this isn't an issue of specificity.  **You can set the list-style on the list (the UL) but you can also override that list-style for individual list items (the LIs).**

You are telling the browser to not use bullets on the list, but YUI tells the browser to use them on individual list items (YUI wins):

```
ul li{ list-style: disc outside; } /* in YUI base.css */

#nav ul.links {
    list-style: none; /* doesn't override styles for LIs, just the UL */
}
```

What you want is to tell the browser not to use them on the list items:

```
ul li{ list-style: disc outside; } /* in YUI base.css */

#nav ul.links li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet you apply the list-style to the li element, in the second to the ul element.

Try

```css
#nav ul.links li
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The latter example probably doesn't work because of [CSS specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html). (A more serious explanation can be found [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).) That is, YUI's base.css rule is:

```css
ul li{ list-style: disc outside; }
```

This is more 'specific' than yours, so the YUI rule is being used. As has been noted several times, you can make your rule more specific by targeting the `li` tags:

```css
#nav ul li{ list-style: none; }
```

Hard to say for sure without looking at your code, but if you don't know about specificity it's certainly worth a read.

Comment: isn't adding the #nav ul li make mine more specific than the general ul li??

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be:

```
#nav ul.links
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the style is the base.css overrides your styles with "!important"? Did you try to add a class to this specific li and make an own style for it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

or

```
.links li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

it should work...